# no visible @interface for 'AsIdentifierManager' declares the selector 'advertisingIdentifier'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get IDFA and use this code：

```
-(IBAction)showMessage
{
    NSString *adId = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
}
```

but it have a error:no visible @interface for 'AsIdentifierManager' declares the selector 'advertisingIdentifier'.I try add "#import " in my .m file's top,but can't fix it.who can help me? thank you.

Comment: Have you linked the AdSuport framework?

Comment: Did you added the exact code here ? I think no. Because in the warning the class name is different. In error it's `AsI` not `ASI`

Comment: sorry,i print worng,my code is ASI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the Ad Support framework to your project. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html)

To link a framework to your project, please follow the steps described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html).

And import it to your class:

```
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
```

Comment: Link is project->Targets->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries->AdSupport.framework?

Comment: thank you.I add the framework,and import header,but have the same error.I forge what?

Comment: add the import to your .h file. clean and build the project.

Comment: I'm so sorry,the word "advertisingIdentifier" I miss 't',worte "advertisingIdenifier".Oh no,3 hours.......